# How to recognize if a website is a DApp?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development

A `Launch App` button often appears on the top-right corner of Ethereum-platform websites. Is this an indication that a link is a link to a DApp (decentralized application)? Are the following two websites DApps?

- https://app.ens.domains/ (Ethereum Name Service for buying decentralized domains)
- https://app.uniswap.org/ (Uniswap decentralized exchange)

What signs, or how can I tell if a website is a DApp? You wouldn't be able to tell just be looking at the URLs above, since even the sub-domain reads "app", not "dapp".

And once you do recognize that a website is a DApp, what can you expect to do with it as givens, compared to regular websites that aren't DApps? I am not even aware of websites that are called "Apps" (centralized apps) in the first place, so what App website can I compare the above Dapps with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Launch App button often appears on the top-right corner of Ethereum-platform websites. Is this an indication that a link is a link to a DApp (decentralized application)?

Not necessarily. The button is usually just a link to a sub-page or page on a sub domain, regardless of what's at the destination.

> Are the following two websites DApps?

They are.

> What signs, or how can I tell if a website is a DApp?

You could check whether certain libraries are injected into the webpage (e.g. `web3.js`, `ethers.js`). There would also need to be some way for the user to connect a wallet, so the associated controls - e.g. a connect button - would need to be present.

> And once you do recognize that a website is a DApp, what can you expect to do with it as givens, compared to regular websites that aren't DApps?

Read and/or write data to the blockchain, depending on what functionality the creator of the site has allowed for.

> I am not even aware of websites that are called "Apps" (centralized apps) in the first place

Calling any website an "app" is just semantics, though you'd expect a website calling itself an app to provide some sort of interactive function, rather than just being presentational.

That being said, PWAs ([Progressive Web Apps](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)) can be created from any type of website.